Ingress - digest authentication
I am trying to implement ingress digest authentication->
My config
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: digest
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-name: "MyRealm"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: "my-ingress-auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-digest-realm: "Restricted Area"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-digest-secret: "my-ingress-auth"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
            service:
                name: api
                port:
                    number: 9995

My secrets config->
apiVersion: v1
data:
  auth: bXl1c2VyOk15UmVhbG06YWZhMTlhZGNjNDZkY2MyNzlhYzIxNGI1ZTQ2ZWYxNDgK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-08-25T00:55:58Z"
  name: my-ingress-auth
  resourceVersion: "838600476"
  uid: dd482a43-fcdd-4433-8e9a-0439268b40af
type: Opaque

Issue is -> service is returning result without authentication.
Curl http://ip_address/api/test

Digest authentication works if I remove following annotations - > "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2" and use Path as - path: /(.*). Any idea ??
